# Problem with creating sockets using CFSocket in Objective-C (iPhone app)

Tags: objective-c, sockets

Ok, I have a problem with building a socket using Objective-C. If you'll take a look at my code below, through help with example code and other sources, I was able to build a complete socket I believe. The problem is that when I compile it, it builds fine (no syntax problems), but there are no sockets being created. As you'll notice I've commented out a lot of things in Server2.m and have isolated the problem to the very beginning when I create the struct for the listeningSocket. By the way, if this helps, it is part of the the server side of server-client application. Does anyone know why I would be getting this problem? Everything seemed to be working fine yesterday, and this morning I thought I would take a different approach to building the sockets, so I tried this. Thanks for any help!

Server_TrialViewController.m

```
#include <CFNetwork/CFSocketStream.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Server2.h"
#import "Client_Test.h"

@interface Server_TrialViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIButton *ServerButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton *ClientButton;
    IBOutlet UILabel *statusLabel;
    Server2 *server;
    Client_Test *client;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) UILabel *statusLabel;
@property(nonatomic, retain) Server2 *server;
@property(nonatomic, retain) Client_Test *client;

-(IBAction)serverButtonPressed;
-(IBAction)clientButtonPressed;
//-(void)sendMessageWithServer:(Server_Test *)SERVER AndClient:(Client_Test *)CLIENT;

@end
```

Server_TrialViewController.h

```
#import "Server_TrialViewController.h"

@implementation Server_TrialViewController
@synthesize statusLabel;
@synthesize server;
@synthesize client;

-(IBAction)serverButtonPressed {
    if ([server start]) {
        [statusLabel setText:@"Success"];
    }
    else {
        if (server.status == NULL) {
            [statusLabel setText: @"No Server: No statUpdate"];
        }
        else {
            [statusLabel setText: @"No Server: Found statUpdate"];
        }
    }       
}


-(IBAction)clientButtonPressed {
    if ([client start]) {
        [statusLabel setText:@"Client Started"];
    }
    else {
        [statusLabel setText:@"Client Not Started"];
    }
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning]; // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview
    // Release anything that's not essential, such as cached data
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Server2.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Server2Delegate.h"

@interface Server2 : NSObject
{
    uint16_t port;
    CFSocketRef listeningSocket;
    id<Server2Delegate> delegate;
    NSNetService* netService;
    NSString *status;
}

// Initialize connection
- (BOOL)start;
- (void)stop;

// Delegate receives various notifications about the state of our server
@property(nonatomic,retain) id<Server2Delegate> delegate;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *status;

@end
```

Server2.m

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <CFNetwork/CFSocketStream.h>

#import "Server2.h"
#import "Connection2.h"
#import "AppConfig2.h"

// Declare some private properties and methods
@interface Server2 ()
@property(nonatomic,assign) uint16_t port;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSNetService* netService;

-(BOOL)createServer;
-(void)terminateServer;

@end

// Implementation of the Server interface
@implementation Server2

@synthesize delegate;
@synthesize port, netService;
@synthesize status;

// Cleanup
- (void)dealloc
{
    self.netService = nil;
    self.delegate = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}


// Create server and announce it
- (BOOL)start
{
    // Start the socket server
    if ( ! [self createServer] )
    {
        status = @"Server Not Created";
        return FALSE;
    }
    status = @"Server Created";
    return TRUE;
}


// Close everything
- (void)stop {
    [self terminateServer];
}

#pragma mark Callbacks

// Handle new connections
- (void)handleNewNativeSocket:(CFSocketNativeHandle)nativeSocketHandle {
    Connection2* connection = [[[Connection2 alloc] initWithNativeSocketHandle:nativeSocketHandle] autorelease];

    // In case of errors, close native socket handle
    if ( connection == nil ) {
        close(nativeSocketHandle);
        return;
    }

    // finish connecting
    if ( ! [connection connect] ) {
        //status = @"Connection Not Made";
        [connection close];
        return;
    }

    //status = @"Connection Made";

    // Pass this on to our delegate
    [delegate handleNewConnection:connection];
}


// This function will be used as a callback while creating our listening socket via 'CFSocketCreate'
static void serverAcceptCallback(CFSocketRef socket, CFSocketCallBackType type, CFDataRef address, const void *data, void *info) {
    Server2 *server = (Server2*)info;

    // We can only process "connection accepted" calls here
    if ( type != kCFSocketAcceptCallBack ) {
        return;
    }

    // for an AcceptCallBack, the data parameter is a pointer to a CFSocketNativeHandle
    CFSocketNativeHandle nativeSocketHandle = *(CFSocketNativeHandle*)data;

    [server handleNewNativeSocket:nativeSocketHandle];
}


#pragma mark Sockets and streams

- (BOOL)createServer
{
    //// PART 1: Create a socket that can accept connections

    // Socket context
    //  struct CFSocketContext {
    //   CFIndex version;
    //   void *info;
    //   CFAllocatorRetainCallBack retain;
    //   CFAllocatorReleaseCallBack release;
    //   CFAllocatorCopyDescriptionCallBack copyDescription;
    //  };
    CFSocketContext socketContext = {0, self, NULL, NULL, NULL};

    listeningSocket = CFSocketCreate(
                                     kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                     PF_INET,        // The protocol family for the socket
                                     SOCK_DGRAM,    // The socket type to create
                                     IPPROTO_UDP,    // The protocol for the socket. TCP vs UDP.
                                     0, //kCFSocketAcceptCallBack,  // New connections will be automatically accepted and the callback is called with the data argument being a pointer to a CFSocketNativeHandle of the child socket.
                                     NULL, //(CFSocketCallBack)&serverAcceptCallback,
                                     &socketContext );

    // Previous call might have failed
    if ( listeningSocket == NULL ) {
        status = @"listeningSocket Not Created";
        return FALSE;
    }
    else {
        status = @"listeningSocket Created";
        return TRUE;
    }
}
    /*
    // getsockopt will return existing socket option value via this variable
    int existingValue = 1;

    // Make sure that same listening socket address gets reused after every connection
    setsockopt( CFSocketGetNative(listeningSocket),
               SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (void *)&existingValue,
               sizeof(existingValue));


    //// PART 2: Bind our socket to an endpoint.
    // We will be listening on all available interfaces/addresses.
    // Port will be assigned automatically by kernel.
    struct sockaddr_in socketAddress;
    memset(&socketAddress, 0, sizeof(socketAddress));
    socketAddress.sin_len = sizeof(socketAddress);
    socketAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;   // Address family (IPv4 vs IPv6)
    socketAddress.sin_port = 0;           // Actual port will get assigned automatically by kernel
    socketAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);    // We must use "network byte order" format (big-endian) for the value here

    // Convert the endpoint data structure into something that CFSocket can use
    NSData *socketAddressData =
    [NSData dataWithBytes:&socketAddress length:sizeof(socketAddress)];

    // Bind our socket to the endpoint. Check if successful.
    if ( CFSocketSetAddress(listeningSocket, (CFDataRef)socketAddressData) != kCFSocketSuccess ) {
        // Cleanup
        if ( listeningSocket != NULL ) {
            status = @"Socket Not Binded";
            CFRelease(listeningSocket);
            listeningSocket = NULL;
        }

        return FALSE;
    }
    status = @"Socket Binded";

    //// PART 3: Find out what port kernel assigned to our socket
    // We need it to advertise our service via Bonjour
    NSData *socketAddressActualData = [(NSData *)CFSocketCopyAddress(listeningSocket) autorelease];

    // Convert socket data into a usable structure
    struct sockaddr_in socketAddressActual;
    memcpy(&socketAddressActual, [socketAddressActualData bytes],
           [socketAddressActualData length]);

    self.port = ntohs(socketAddressActual.sin_port);

    //// PART 4: Hook up our socket to the current run loop
    CFRunLoopRef currentRunLoop = CFRunLoopGetCurrent();
    CFRunLoopSourceRef runLoopSource = CFSocketCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, listeningSocket, 0);
    CFRunLoopAddSource(currentRunLoop, runLoopSource, kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
    CFRelease(runLoopSource);

    return TRUE;
}
*/

- (void) terminateServer {
    if ( listeningSocket != nil ) {
        CFSocketInvalidate(listeningSocket);
        CFRelease(listeningSocket);
        listeningSocket = nil;
    }
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark NSNetService Delegate Method Implementations

// Delegate method, called by NSNetService in case service publishing fails for whatever reason
- (void)netService:(NSNetService*)sender didNotPublish:(NSDictionary*)errorDict {
    if ( sender != self.netService ) {
        return;
    }

    // Stop socket server
    [self terminateServer];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For people looking for information about CFSocket server here's the answer: The code above is working fine if you change "SOCK_DGRAM" to "SOCK_STREAM".

Comment: CFSocketStream includes the word "stream" to indicate it is for stream oriented connections. In Apple, they think this is just obvious as can be, but clearly it is not.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting `kCFSocketAcceptCallBack` to something other than 0?

If you're interested in socket programming on Mac OS X or the iPhone, I suggest you look at [this example](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/PictureSharing/index.html) from Apple's documentation.